# Find the congruence of $4^{578} \pmod 7$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Find the congruence of $4^{578} \pmod 7$.

Can anyone calculate the congruence without using computer?

Thank you!

Comment: [Congruence Modulo with large exponents](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/165670/congruence-modulo-with-large-exponents)

Comment: Note that $4^3=64\equiv 1\pmod 7$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **Fermat's Little theorem**:

*If p is a prime and a is an integer, then $a^{p-1}\equiv1$ (mod p), 
if p does not divide a.*

$4^{6}\equiv1 (mod 7)$

Since $4^{578}=(4^{6})^{96}\cdot4^{2}$, we can conclude that$4^{578}\equiv1^{96}\cdot4^{2}(mod 7)$.

Hence$4^{578}\equiv2(mod 7)$.

Comment: Could any one review it?

Answer (score 6):

Use the fact that $$4^{3} \equiv 1 \ (\text{mod 7})$$ along with if $a \equiv b \ (\text{mod} \: m)$ then $a^{n} \equiv b^{n} \ (\text{mod}\: m)$.