# Find 3 last digits of power of power where base is huge

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modular-arithmetic

Given $a=135797531$, find 3 last digits of $a^{a^{320}}$.

Now, I know that I need to solve: $a^{a^{320}}(\mod 1000)$.

What I know: $a\in{U_n}$ (Euler's group - Multiplicative group of integers modulo n) so that means Euler's theorem applies and $a^{\phi(1000)}\equiv1(\mod 1000)$ where $\phi(1000)=400$.

I also saw [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1406764/201720162015-mod-1000?rq=1) that the exponent is congruent to the exponent modulo $\phi(1000)$ but I don't understand why and under what conditions..

I don't know how to continue from here..help!

Comment: Calculate $b=a\,\text{mod}\,1000$ and $c=a\,\text{mod}\,400$ then you'll need to find $b^{c^{320}}$. We can then calculate $\varphi(400)$ and use Euler's theorem again to reduce the power of $320$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Theorem**: If $b$ and $c$ are non-negative natural numbers, $m$ and $a$ are co-prime, $b = c\enspace\text{mod}\,\varphi(m)$, then $a^b = a^c\enspace\text{mod}\,m$.

**Proof**: Without loss of generality, suppose that $b>c$. Then $b=c+k\cdot\varphi(m)$ where $k$ is a natural number. $$a^b = a^{c+k\cdot\varphi(m)} = a^c\cdot (a^{\varphi(m)})^k = a^c \enspace\text{mod}\,m$$

Where we used Euler's theorem for $a^{\varphi(m)} = 1\enspace\text{mod}\,m$, and the fact that $$a'=a''\enspace\text{mod}\,m\,\land\,b'=b''\enspace\text{mod}\,m\implies a'b'=a''b''\enspace\text{mod}\,m$$

***End of proof***.

Suppose we want to calculate $a^{a^{320}}$ modulo $1000$. We can first calculate $a^{320}$ modulo $\varphi(1000)=400$ since $a$ and $1000$ are co-prime, using the theorem above.

To calculate $a^{320}$ modulo $400$, we can calculate $320$ modulo $\varphi(400)=160$, because, again, $400$ and $a$ are co-prime.

$$320 = 0\enspace\text{mod}\,160 \implies a^{320} = 1\enspace\text{mod}\,400 \implies a^{a^{320}}=a\enspace\text{mod}\,1000 $$
And because $a=531\enspace\text{mod}\,1000$, then
$$a^{a^{320}}=531\enspace\text{mod}\,1000  $$

Comment: I think you wrote 360 instead of 320 in exponents' exponent.
And how did you find $a (mod 400)$?

Comment: @eagleye yes, you're right, thanks. I've edited my post for more clarity, and also corrected my mistakes. It's a lot easier now that there's $320$ in exponent

Comment: Amazing, thanks a bunch! the second explanation really cleared things up.