# remainder when $48^{45}$ is divided by 35?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

What is the remainder when $48^{45}$ is divided by 35?

I tried using Euler's theorem, which led to Re$\frac{{13}^{21}}{35}$

I don't know how to move ahead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Modular exponentiation by hand ($a^b\bmod c$)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81228/modular-exponentiation-by-hand-ab-bmod-c)

Comment: As linked in the dupe, using the [expt $\rm\color{#c00}{lcm}$ method](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/165728/242) as in Carmichael's generalization of Euler-Fermat
$$\begin{align} 
&\bmod 5\!:\ \ \ \color{#0a0}{48}^{\large\color{#c00}4}\equiv 1\ \ \text{by Fermat (or $\,(\color{#0a0}{-2})^4\equiv 1$)}\\
&\bmod 7\!:\ \ \ 48^{\large\color{#c00}2}\equiv 1\ \ {\rm by}\ \ 48\equiv -1\\
\Rightarrow\, &\bmod 35\!:\ 48^{\large\color{darkorange}4}\equiv 1\ \ {\rm by}\ \ \color{darkorange}4 
 = {\rm lcm}(\color{#c00}{4,2})\end{align}\qquad$$

Comment: hence $\bmod 35\!:\ 48^{\Large 1+\color{darkorange}4\:\!n}\equiv 48\,$ by [mod order reduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2033681/242) (or directly $\,48(48^{\Large\color{darkorange}4})^{\Large n}\equiv 48(1)^{\Large n}\equiv 48)\ \ $

Answer (score 2):

We split the congruence equation to mod $5$ and mod $7$ as below:
$48^{45}\equiv (-1)^{45}\equiv -1\equiv 6 \pmod{7}$,
$48^{45}\equiv 3^{45}\equiv 3\times3^{2\times22}\equiv3\times9^{22}\equiv3\times(-1)^{22}\equiv3\pmod{5}$,
Which then we can combine as below:
Assume the remainder is $r$. Since $r\equiv6\pmod{7}$, there exist positive integer $t$ s.t.
$r=7t+6$
Then, we plug into the other equation to obtain:
$7t+6\equiv3\pmod{5}$
$2t+1\equiv3\pmod{5}$
$2t\equiv2\pmod5$
$t\equiv1\pmod5$
Since the remainder should not exceed $35$, we choose $t=1$ which then leads to $r=13$. Hence $48^{45}$ leaves a remainder of $13$ when divided by $35$.

Comment: The combining part here is often called the Chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242.)

Answer (score 2):

Beginning like the answer of Matti P., observe that $48^2\equiv 13^2\equiv 29 \bmod 35$

Note that $29\equiv -6 \bmod 35$, so $48^4 \equiv (-6)^2\equiv 1 \bmod 35$.

From this we conclude that $48^{44}\equiv 1 \bmod 35$ and $48^{45}\equiv 48\equiv 13 \bmod 35$

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242.)

Answer (score 1):

Let's try computing the remainder for some smaller powers.

- $48 \equiv 13 \mod 45$
- $48^2 \equiv 13^2 = 169 \equiv 29 \mod 35$
- $48^5 \equiv 13^5 = (13^2)(13^2)(13^1) = (29)(29)(13) = 10~933 \equiv 13 \mod 35$
- $48^{45} \equiv 13^{45} = (13^5)^9 \equiv (13)^9 = \ldots$

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242.)